# What does "all this" mean?

Tags: meaning

> **All this**, Mr. Brownlow, although himself somewhat of an impetuous gentleman: knowing his friend's peculiarities, bore with great good humour; as Mr. Grimwig, at tea, was graciously pleased to express his entire approval of the muffins, matters went on very smoothly; and Oliver, who made one of the party, began to feel more at his ease than he had yet done in the fierce old gentleman's presence.

From Oliver Twist

I don't understand why it comes out. Is it an absolute noun or something?

Comment: A usage chart for the *exact* cited text here might be distorted by endless reprints and citations, so I changed ***himself*** to ***herself*** for [this chart.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=herself+somewhat+of%2Cherself+something+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=20) But as you'll see from the chart, if Dickens were writing today, he'd probably have said *Mr. Brownlow, although himself **something** of an impetuous gentleman...* The meaning is just *Mr. Brownlow bore/accepted **all this*** [something described by earlier text] *with good humour...*

Comment: "All this" is an NP functioning as object of the verb "bore". Functionally, "all this" is called  a preposed complement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'All this' usually refers to something mentioned or described just before, or at the time of speaking (e.g. if indicated by a gesture). So we look in the previous paragraph -

> Now, the fact was, that in the inmost recesses of his own heart, Mr.
> Grimwig was strongly disposed to admit that Oliver's appearance and
> manner were unusually prepossessing; but he had a strong appetite for
> contradiction, sharpened on this occasion by the finding of the
> orange-peel; and, inwardly determining that no man should dictate to
> him whether a boy was well-looking or not, he had resolved, from the
> first, to oppose his friend. When Mr. Brownlow admitted that on no one
> point of inquiry could he yet return a satisfactory answer; and that
> he had postponed any investigation into Oliver's previous history
> until he thought the boy was strong enough to bear it; Mr. Grimwig
> chuckled maliciously. And he demanded, with a sneer, whether the
> housekeeper was in the habit of counting the plate at night; because,
> if she didn't find a tablespoon or two missing some sunshiny morning,
> why, he would be content to- and so forth.

That is what 'all this' refers to. It is [what]/[the object of] 'Mr Brownlow bore'.

Comment: I feel like the OP is also confused by the highly inverted syntax and might have missed the fact that "all this" is the object of "Mr. Brownlow bore." It might be nice to edit to address this too.

Comment: @AndyBonner It's not inversion, but **preposing**. Here, it is the complement of "bore", i.e. all this", that is preposed.

Comment: @BillJ Thanks for correcting me. If we're going to be sticklers, I think I might still call it an object rather than a complement, though.